# HTML Helpers used by StackOverflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What was Stack Overflow built with?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with)

I dont know if this question stands on meta.stackoverflow... If it doesn't close it...

I know StackOverflow is built with asp.net MVC and they would have used many HTML Helpers..

- List of HTML Helpers used by StackOverflow?

If any one knows it can share it with me...

Comment: @Æther: my thoughts exactly.